# Marketo send test failed

Tags: email, marketo

Try to send a sample of an email and receive a notice that the Marketo send test failed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two token-related reasons that Send Sample may fail:

You may have an invalid value for a token in your email. If there is an incorrect token value, the send sample will not work.
Example: If you have the token for first name written like this {{lead.FirstName:default=Hello}}, when you try to approve the email Marketo will let you know that the token value is incorrect. The correct token value is  {{lead.First Name:default=Hello}}. For this example if you change the token value to {{lead.First Name:default=Hello}}, Marketo will allow you to approve the email and it will allow you to do a send sample.

You may have a token in the From or Reply-To line that is not populating with an email address
Example: If you have a token in the Reply-To like this one, {{lead.Email Address:default=edit me}}, then the Send Sample using the default will have "edit me" in the Reply-To, which is not an email address.  Marketo cannot send an email without a Reply-To email address, so the Send Sample will fail.

If any of the above does not apply, run the following tests and provide the information to Marketo Support

Clone the email in question and test to send as a sample
Create a new email and test to send as a sample
Send the email via a live campaign or a [single flow step](https://nation.marketo.com/external-link.jspa?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.marketo.com%2Fdisplay%2Fpublic%2FDOCS%2FRun%2Ba%2BSingle%2BFlow%2BStep%2Bfrom%2Ba%2BSmart%2BList) to a test lead